# Poptoviewcontroller not working properly after receiving response from payU

Tags: ios, xcode, payu

I am integrated payU payment gateway in my application. After I have made successful payment I am not able to go previous viewController from where I have pushes payU view for payment.

Steps:
I am using tabBar in my application with 5 tabs. Each view in tab is added in navigationController so u can push views.
Suppose I have selected homeTab bar and from home I have selected product which I have purchase.
Then it goes to Mycart view then on click of buy Now I pushes another viewController and then on click of place order btn on that view I am started payment using payU .

It means I am pushing payU views and make payment. After successful payment done receiveResponse method is called where I am getting payment response.

If I put code to pop to place order view it get popped to home View even I doesn't write any code for pop it pops to home.

Comment: what is issue and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am pushing payU view from my place order view. I want to pop to place order view after payment successful using payU.

Comment: I am going to place order through homeView->MyCart->PlaceOrder

Comment: show your code which is not working !! I mean how you pop!

Comment: when I pop after successful payment using payU I am goes to Home view. Don't know why this is happen

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: make sure that `payU` sdk is not automatically popping current viewController! and make sure that you are not presenting any viewcontroller in above navigation sequence!

Comment: I checked in payU code they are not automatically pop.

Comment: After receiving response from payU when I had checked self.navigationController. It is nil after receiving response from payU

Comment: this is the problem. Try to figure out why it is getting `nil`. once try `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` instead of `popViewController` after successful payment!

Comment: Yes I am getting navigationController nil. when I try to dismiss using [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; still I am not able to go proper viewController

Comment: what happens when you dissmiss ?

Comment: when I am dismiss view I am getting payU first view visible on screen

Comment: I am not getting !!! you should add some code and screenshots of your issues to clearly understanding!

Comment: I have solved it as I am adding observer in two views by mistake because of which this scenario happens. Observer for receiving response from payU